# ossbuild - use gstreamer bindings in C# - How do i install it correctly?

Tags: c#, dll, binding, gstreamer

I want to start with gstreamer and the first stop i made was ossbuild.
I stumbled upon this [site](http://www.klopfenstein.net/lorenz.aspx/setting-up-gstreamer-and-net-on-windows)

I then installed ossbuild, imported the c# bindings dll and tried to compile the small program.

At the first line (`Application.init()`) it throws an Exception: `Dllnotfoundexception for "libgstreamer-0.10.dll"`.

```
using System; 
using Gst; 

namespace GStreamerTest { 
    class Program { 
        static void Main(string[] args) { 
            Application.Init(); //this throws the Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Loaded GStreamer {0}.{1}...", Gst.Version.Major, Gst.Version.Minor); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I searched for this dll and added it to the buildpath. It then started to ask for another dll. I added it too and the games started again and again.

I guess the installation did not set a global variable or something like that, and that is why the program does not find the dlls at the right location.

But I have no idea at all about these things. Does somebody know how to do this correctly?

Thanks for any help in advance,
jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add These Environment Variables Manually (It should be added automatically at the time of installing Gstreamer ossbuild)

Var Name : GST_PLUGIN_PATH
Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\OSSBuild\GStreamer\v0.10.7\lib\gstreamer-0.10

Var Name: OSSBUILD_GSTREAMER_DIR
Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\OSSBuild\GStreamer\v0.10.7\

Var Name: OSSBUILD_GSTREAMER_SDK_DIR
Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\OSSBuild\GStreamer\v0.10.7\sdk\

Add These to the "Path" Variable.

C:\Program Files (x86)\OSSBuild\GStreamer\v0.10.7\sdk\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\OSSBuild\GStreamer\v0.10.7\bin;

If you install at c:/Program Files (x86)  ,  the application should run.

Comment: first: thx!

second: how do i add these environment variables ? over cmd or at visual studio?
Sry i've never worked with Environment vars

Comment: Go to System Properties (Open My Computer>RightClick>Properties)  Click Advanced tab.     You should find Environment Variables button.

Comment: ah thx! lets see if i find this. path and sys vars were always confusing to me